# How to make 'google calendar'-like table in android

Tags: android, calendar

I want to create a 'google-calendar'-like table, which shows in landscape orientation:

[image: desired result].

Is there a simple way to do that or do I have to dig in google calendar source code? 
I don't need the calendar itself, only the table for it.

Answer (score 0):

[**Grid View**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) is what you need I guess, simply read through it.[image]

Comment: No. I guess i have to use recyclerview with gridLayoutManager with different types of items, including draggable column-headers and static row-headers. But i hope there is ready solution

Comment: @HuezMorjovich were you able to create the calendar table?? I need it as well. Please advise. Thanks.